# filter message recipients in php Symfony

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I created a form allowing users to send messages to the admin only.
As for the admin he can send it to whoever he wants.

My form works very well and the messages are sent, but the problem is that users who are not Admin can also write to each other.

I need to filter in my form in order to return in the "select" all the users if the role of the person connected is ADMIN or only the admin if the person connected is a simple user.

I tried to do it by following the Symfony doc but I can't do it.

here is the error:

> Doctrine\Persistence\AbstractManagerRegistry::getManagerForClass(): Argument #1 ($class) must be of type string, Closure given, called in C:\laragon\www\MinaCakes\vendor\symfony\doctrine-bridge \Form\Type\DoctrineType.php on line 181

the problem comes from my request (I think)

basic I had in this place:

```
'class' => Users::class
```

and everything worked very well but as I said everyone could send messages to each other.

```
use App\Entity\Messages;
use App\Entity\Users;
use App\Repository\UsersRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

    class MessageType extends AbstractType
    {
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
        {
            $builder
                ->add('title', TextType::class, [
                    "attr" => [
                        "class" => "form-control"
                    ]
                ])
                ->add('message', TextareaType::class, [
                    "attr" => [
                        "class" => "form-control"
                    ]
                ])
                ->add('recipient', EntityType::class, [
                    "class" => function ( UsersRepository $ur) {
                        $user = $_SESSION["user"];
                        if ($user["roles"] === "ROLE_ADMIN"){
                            return Users::class;
                        }
                        return $ur->createQueryBuilder('u', 'users')
                                    ->select('App\\Entity\\Users', 'c')
                                    ->where("u.roles = ROLE_ADMIN");
                    },
                    "choice_label" => "firstname",
                    "attr" => [
                        "class" =>"form-control"
                    ]
                ]) 
                ->add('Envoyer', SubmitType::class, [
                    "attr" =\> \[
                        "class" => "btn btn-primary"
                    ]
                \])
            ;
        }
    
        public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
        {
            $resolver->setDefaults([
                'data_class' => Messages::class,
            \]);
        }
    }



#[Route("/send", name: '_send')]
public function send(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $em):           Response
{
$message = new Messages();
$form = $this->createForm(MessageType::class, $message);

            $form->handleRequest($request);
    
            if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
    
                $message
                    ->setTitle($form->get('title')->getData())
                    ->setMessage($form->get('message')->getData())
                    ->setRecipient($form->get('recipient')->getData())
                    ->setSender($this->getUser())
                ;
    
                $em->persist($message);
                $em->flush();
    
                $this->addFlash("message", "Votre mesage a été envoyé.");
                return $this->redirectToRoute("messages_view");
            }
    
            return $this->render("messages/send.html.twig", [
                "form" => $form->createView()
            ]);
        }
```

Comment: another mistake I made is forgetting the "%" around the "ROLE_ADMIN" and in some cases, depending on the syntax, this can prevent the code from working. so if this can be useful to anyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the query_builder option
https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#using-a-custom-query-for-the-entities

example (not tested)

```
    $builder->add('recipient', EntityType::class, [
    "class" => Users::class,
    "choice_label" => "firstname",
    'query_builder' => function (UsersRepository $repository) use (Users $user) {
        if(!$user->hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
            return $repository->createQueryBuilder('u', 'users')
                ->select(Users::class, 'u')
                ->where("ROLE_ADMIN IN u.roles");
        }  
        return $repository->createQueryBuilder('u', 'users')
                ->select(Users::class, 'u');

    },
    "attr" => [
        "class" =>"form-control"
    ]
])
```